# How to optimize damerau-levenshtein in mysql?

Tags: mysql, optimization, fuzzy

I installed Damerau-Levenshtein plugin in MySQL. It runs well. However, after I reach more than 150,000 rows, retrieving data gets slower (4 seconds), although I applied damlevlim, limiting computation only to difference of 10.

It was less than 1 second at less than 20,000 rows. I guess, it will significantly be slower, once I reach 1 millions rows.

All relevant fields have been indexed.

The query is simple:

```
SET @kisaranmirip=maxdifference;
SET @current_id=tmid;
SET @cari=caritext;

SET @ret=(SELECT indonesian 
    FROM tm 
    WHERE 
        tm_id<tmid 
    ORDER BY damlevlim(@cari, english,maxdifference) 
    LIMIT 1);

UPDATE babel.tm
SET indonesian=@ret
WHERE tm_id=tmid
```

Please your insights to optimize the process. Thank you.